# Given any finite surjections $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ with $|Y|<|Z|$ does there always $\exists x\in g^{-1}[Z\setminus Y]:|f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}]|>1$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

Given any three finite sets $X,Y,Z$ satisfying $1\leq |Y|<|Z|\leq |X|$ as well as surjections $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ is it always true that $\exists x\in g^{-1}[Z\setminus Y]:|f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}]|>1$?

Or equivalently must there always be distinct $p,q\in X$ such that $f(p)=f(q)$ and $g(q)\in Z\setminus Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $X=Z=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$. Let $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=1$, and let $g$ be the identity function. The only $x\in X$ such that $g(x)\in Z\setminus Y$ is $2$, and it is the only element of $X$ whose image under $f$ is $1$.